# How to flip an image without moving it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the example below, click on logo and you'll see - it is flipped but also moved
How to flip it without moving ?
I also tried this, without success:

```
.flip{transform:scaleX(-1) translatex(-50%);}
```

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('flip');
 });
```

```css
.flip{transform:scaleX(-1);}

.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background:darkorange;
 }
img{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:140px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translatex(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrap'>
<img src='https://abuena.net/img/logo_01.png' alt='img'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to include the `translate` property in the `.flip` class.

Note that the order of properties is important, eg. `scale` before `translate`, and after will give you different outputs:

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flip');
});
```

```css
.flip {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(-1);
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: darkorange;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 140px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrap'>
  <img src='https://abuena.net/img/logo_01.png' alt='img'>
</div>
```

Comment: *Note that the order of properties is important, eg. scale before translate, and after will give you different outputs:* - this is very relevant, thank you for including that and not just "do it like this".

Comment: Also note that a "new" transform will replace all of the existing transform properties, they are not cumulative  Hence the need here to reapply the original -50%.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply an opposite `translateX` to counter the `scaleX -1`:

```
.flip{
transform:scaleX(-1) translatex(50%)
}
```

Note that a "new" `transform` will replace all of the existing `transform` properties, they do not add on.

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('flip');
 });
```

```css
.flip{
transform:scaleX(-1) translatex(50%)
}

.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background:darkorange;
 }
img{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:140px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translatex(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrap'>
<img src='https://abuena.net/img/logo_01.png' alt='img'>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I will accept Anurag's solution, just because it is posted earlier

Comment: No worries - the part about the order being relevant is quite important.